# Stata counting observations across multiple columns into one table

Tags: datatable, count, stata, frequency

I need a table of 3 columns:

- Column 1 counts how often the letter a,b,c,d are prevalent in the variable 1 to 3 across all rows
- Column 2 counts how often the number a,b,c,d are prevalent in the variable 4 to 6 across all rows
- Column 3 subtracts 2 from 1

The data looks like this:

| observation | var 1 | var 2 | var 3 | var 4 | var 5 | var 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | d | c | a | b |
| 2 | b | c | d | b | a | d |
| 3 | b | d | a | c | d | a |

The table should look something like this:

|  | Column 1 (var1-3) | Column 2 (var4-6) | Column 3) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | 3 | -1 |
| b | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| c | 1 | 2 | -1 |
| d | 3 | 2 | 1 |

I am using Stata and I have no idea where to start. I have tried with `tabulate`, `tab1`, `table` but none of it seems to suit my needs.

Comment: This isn't clear to me without a proper data example -- please see the `stata` tag for details -- and shows no attempt at code.

Comment: @NickCox I actually inserted a table to show both the data and desired output. But it' was not showing correctly. I think I fixed it now. With respect to the code, I specifically mentioned I had no clue where to even start so, true.. no code.

Comment: That seems clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are likely to be many other ways to do this.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte observation str1(var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6)
1 "a" "b" "d" "c" "a" "b"
2 "b" "c" "d" "b" "a" "d"
3 "b" "d" "a" "c" "d" "a"
end

rename (var4-var6) (war#), addnumber 
reshape long var war, i(obs) j(which)

rename (var war) (value=)
reshape long value, i(obs which) j(group) string 

contract group value 
reshape wide _freq, i(value) j(group) string

char _freqvar[varname] "var1-var3"
char _freqwar[varname] "var4-var6"
gen difference = _freqvar - _freqwar
list, subvarname abbrev(10) noobs 

  +--------------------------------------------+
  | value   var1-var3   var4-var6   difference |
  |--------------------------------------------|
  |     a           2           3           -1 |
  |     b           3           2            1 |
  |     c           1           2           -1 |
  |     d           3           2            1 |
  +--------------------------------------------+
```